# Maven shade plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-shade-plugin

I am trying to build an assembly from my maven multi-module build with the maven shade plugin and the maven assembly plugin. What I need is a structure like that:

***assembly.zip***
------------- **dllDir**
----------------- *some dll's located in sub-module*
------------- **.netDir**
----------------- *the full jar (consisting of all module jars) as .net lib (va ikvm)*
------------- **fulljarDir**
----------------- *the java full jar (consisting of all module jars)*
----------------- *the java api jar (only some classes)*
----------------- *full-jar sources*
----------------- *api-jar sources*
------------- **libs**
----------------- *All sub-module libs ("normal"-jar, sources-jar, jar-with-dependencies)*
------------- **extlibDir**
----------------- *some other jars/dlls that are located in some sub-module dirs*
------------- **docDir**
----------------- *some documentation (copied from assembly project itself)*

Currently I am using the shade plugin in the assembly project to create the *full-jar* and the *api-jar* (all modules are described as dependencies of the assembly project) with their sources.

I collect the the jar's and dll's from the modules by using the assembly plugin (with and assembly descriptor):

```
<moduleSets>
    <moduleSet>
        <includeSubModules>false</includeSubModules>
        <sources>
            <outputDirectoryMapping>libs/${module.basedir.name}
            </outputDirectoryMapping>
            <excludeSubModuleDirectories>
                true
            </excludeSubModuleDirectories>
            <fileSets>
                <fileSet>
                    <directory>/target/</directory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>*dependencies.jar</include>
                        <include>*javadoc.jar</include>
                        <include>*sources.jar</include>
                    </includes>
                    <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
                </fileSet>
                <fileSet>
                    <directory>/native/usblibs.Linux/Release/</directory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>*.so</include>
                    </includes>
                    <outputDirectory>../../dllDir</outputDirectory>
                </fileSet>
                <fileSet>
                    <directory>/native/usb.Linux/lib/libusb-1.0/</directory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>*.so</include>
                    </includes>
                    <outputDirectory>../../usb</outputDirectory>
                </fileSet>
                <fileSet>
                    <directory>/native/usb.Linux/lib/usblib/i386/
                    </directory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>*.so</include>
                    </includes>
                    <outputDirectory>../../usb</outputDirectory>
                </fileSet>
            </fileSets>
        </sources>
    </moduleSet>
</moduleSets>
```

The problem is now that I am using the shade plugin for compiling the fat jar (of all modules). But I am using modules as well, so the packaging needs to be `pom`and that leads to the bevaviour, that the shade plugin creates pom (with the sources in it) instead of a jar. If I use the `<finalName>`tag in shade, I can rename the full artifact to jar, but the gernerated sources are not renamed.

Any hints or tricks? Maybe there are better ways to produce such an assembly?

Best,
 Jan

Comment: It's not clear why if you use modules, the packaging should be `pom`? What modules do you refer? Assembly `<moduleSets>`? But they are unrelated to packaging.

Comment: If I choose packaging `jar`, I cannot add any modules in the modules section in the `pom`. I refer all the modules of the project in the pom to collect the dll's (that are generated in the build process) from the modules via the `moduleSets`.

Comment: Maybe I am on the wrong track...An idea to build an assemby like described in my original post is highly appreciated

Comment: Ah, OK! You'd better split a parent pom with modules. Now you want to mix too many things in one module. When you separate them you'll feel better, as two your modules will become simpler and will do just things they are aimed to do.

Comment: Ok, youre right, but I have already a separate parent pom, I have only the modules in the assembly pom, because of the assemby desriptor in my snippet drom above. I need to collect non-jars from the modules and I didn't find any way other than using the ModuleSets....:(

Comment: Unfortunately, the exchange of any resources should go via repository thus via artifacts. Namely your modules need to generate (= attach to cycle) extra artifacts with e.g. another classifier. You can do it using `maven-assebly-plugin` in your modules. Later you can collect them in your destination module.